# wordpress doesn't register custom jquery

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress site and I wish to add a custom chunk of jQuery code to the site. The code below was meant to trigger when a user selects a radio button, linking that change with another change within the page. The DOM generated puts ids on the elements and so I proceeded to bind events to the elements. Problem is that the events trigger when looking in firebug, but my functions don't get triggered.

I've tried to:

- put the event bindings inside the document ready...
- outside document ready...
- added the script in the header....
- added the script to the footer ...
- using both the shorthand '$' and jQuery when calling the event
- tried the e.preventDefault() method

and every method has the same result, the function does not trigger. I've also tried different events (click, select, change...) with no luck.

Here's the script:

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var processing = false;
$('#shipping_method_local_delivery').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("this is the click");
        });

$('#payment_method_rba_etomitreba').change(function(){
    if (processing) {return;}
    processing = true;
    $('#shipping_method_local_delivery').click();
    processing = false;
});

$('#shipping_method_local_pickup').change(function(){
    if (processing) {return;}
    processing = true;  
    $('#payment_method_cod').click();
    processing = false;
});

$('#payment_method_cod').change(function(){
    if (processing) {return;}
    processing = true;
    $('#shipping_method_local_pickup').click();
    processing = false;
});

$('#payment_method_bacs').change(function(){
    if (processing) {return;}
    processing = true;
    $('#shipping_method_local_delivery').click();
    processing = false;
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Odds are the selectors are not returning the DOM elements when being run. This can happen if the elements are being created by another set of javascript/jquery.

Using firebug, set a breakpoint at your first attempt to bind an event handler, and in your watch window set a watch for the jQuery selector, and see if the array is 0 or populated.

If the DOM elements are being created afterwards, you may want to look at using the jQuery on method http://api.jquery.com/on/ . It can be a bit tricky to wrap your mind around...but once you got it your code should work with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

try changing all the '$' with jQuery.

Comment: Yeah, I have but it still didn't get the script to be triggered.